# Backbone model is a jquery event

Tags: backbone.js

In the router of my Backbone app that I'm implementing Devise with, I do this to present the user registration form

```
var registrationView = new app.Views.UserRegistrationView({ model: app.Models.User})
```

In the view, I'm setting the variables from the form on the model

```
 this.model.set({email : email, password_confirmation: password_confirmation, password: password});
```

However, when I press submit, I'm getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'set'
```

I did a console.log on `this.model`, and it shows that `this.model` is actually a jQuery event rather than a Backbone model. Can you see what I might be doing wrong?

```
jQuery.Event {originalEvent: Event, type: "submit", isDefaultPrevented: function, timeStamp: 1379115192123, jQuery110205039490440394729: true…}
altKey: undefined
bubbles: true
cancelable: true
ctrlKey: undefined
currentTarget: form#signup-form.form-horizontal
data: undefined
delegateTarget: div
eventPhase: 3
handleObj: Object
isDefaultPrevented: function returnTrue() {
jQuery110205039490440394729: true
metaKey: false
originalEvent: Event
relatedTarget: undefined
shiftKey: undefined
target: form#signup-form.form-horizontal
timeStamp: 1379115192123
type: "submit"
view: undefined
which: undefined
__proto__: Object
 devise.js?body=1:46
function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }
```

I create my user model the usual way

```
app.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({...
```

Update

Here's the render function from the UserRegistrationView.

```
    render: function(){      
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    return this; 

    },

     initialize:function () {


         _.templateSettings = {
        interpolate : /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
        escape : /\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g,
        evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
    };
        var template = $('#signup_template').html();
        this.template = _.template(template);

    },
```

In router

```
 signup: function(){...
    var registrationView = new app.Views.UserRegistrationView({ model: app.Models.User})
    this.showView('#content', registrationView);

 showView: function(selector, view) { 
    if (this.currentView){      
        this.currentView.close();
    }
    $(selector).html(view.render().el);
    this.currentView = view;

    return view;
     }
```

Update 2

```
app.Views.UserRegistrationView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
    'submit form': 'signup',

    },

   signup: function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password_confirmation = $('#password_confirmation').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();         
    this.model.set({email : email, password_confirmation: password_confirmation, password: password});
    this.model.createUser();
```

Comment: can you share your `render`?

Comment: can you share your submit code too? I think you need to scope `this`.

Comment: where is the submit listener?

Comment: @DanielA.White I updated the code with the event and the signup function.

Comment: @dbrin I'm listening for submission of the form in the UserRegistrationView and calling the signup method when it's submitted.

Comment: I noticed you are doing { model: app.Models.User} can you try { model: new app.Models.User()}  ?

Comment: what version of backbone are you using?

Comment: @dbrin: That's actually the answer. Or would be the answer with a bit of explanation. View instances expect to see a model instance in their `model` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you are doing

```
{ model: app.Models.User}
```

change this to

```
 { model: new app.Models.User()}
```

Answer (score -1):

My best guess is that you aren't using the right `this` for your submit function. You should supply the optional `context` argument.